# Asp.Net C# - Executing stored proc on keypress event

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, keypress

I know this sounds stupid. Also i know that this is hurting the server because of process every keypress event.

But calling stored proc in keypress event is the only solution i've got so far to my problem.

but sometimes the result is not right when pressing too fast. This is because it always changes the value in textbox.

Can anyone suggest me how to do it properly? in javascript maybe or other option.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Rx and using throttling from key press events so that you don't immediately fire the stored proc on key down.

Comment: Agree with @TheSenator re the delay. Also, it would be ideal to have an in-memory cache instead of hitting a database continuously. This won't work very well if your site is high traffic.

Comment: You appear to be trying to reinvent the wheel called "autocomplete". Use a pre-existing solution.

Comment: @DvS How does in-memory cache working? can you give me idea whats the process behind it?

Does this applicable when my stored proc is doing several computations and joining several tables and pulling new values everytime the keypress triggers??

Comment: An in-memory cache is usually a static/singleton either in-process (running as part of your web application), or that is part of a service, like self-hosted Web API. In principle it represents information that does not need to be 100% up to date, so it may not suit your needs. But it does seem strange that you need 100% current data for each keypress. This kind of cache can a bit of work to get up and running and syncing with new data, but it's the way to go if you want performance for a high traffic site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set a time out with javascript, for example 0.25 second before calling your stored proc.

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">

<script>
  var myVar;
  function myFunction() {   
    clearTimeout(myVar);
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 2000); // 2 seconds
  }
</script>
```

In your case instead of alert("Hello") you want to call the SP